# is it possible to have ajax response as HTML?

Tags: html, ajax

I have an HTML with an UL, i want to know if it's possible to append children using an ajax response, example:

I know this way doesn't work, but i was wondering if the ajax response can also be **elements**

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <ul></ul>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS

```
var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
request.open('GET','data.txt',false);
request.send();
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
ul.innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

DATA.TXT

```
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
```

I can see the response is being accurately retrieved from the data file, but nothing shows up on the HTML

Comment: why not a .html file?

Comment: getElementsByTagName will return an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
ul.innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

`document.getElementsByTagName` accesses all elements with the specified tagname. So you have to specify the index

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr52dsy3/)

Comment: Yeah i forgot i was retrieving an array of elements, and this works like a charm :D now i will try to up my work to get the response from a php file instead of a data file. Thank you !